# Modifying attribute access for the __main__ module (the details of name resolution)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, namespaces

## Information collected from the docs

Concerning [name resolution](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) the documentation is not perfectly clear. It uses the terms *scope* and *namespace* but is not precise about how they come into effect and when exactly a `NameError` is raised:

> When a name is used in a code block, it is resolved using the nearest enclosing scope. The set of all such scopes visible to a code block is called the block’s environment.
>
> When a name is not found at all, a `NameError` exception is raised.

This however doesn't explain where exactly the name is searched for. Concerning namespaces we get the following information:

> Names are resolved in the top-level namespace by searching the global namespace, i.e. the namespace of the module containing the code block, [...]

And further, regarding `__main__`:

> The namespace for a module is automatically created the first time a module is imported. The main module for a script is always called `__main__`.

[This part of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#module-__main__) further states that

> `'__main__'` is the name of the scope in which top-level code executes.

## Relevant code

Combining the above statements, I suppose that whenever a name is to be resolved in the *"top-level script environment"* (*"top-level namespace"*) this happens happens by checking `sys.modules['__main__']` (similar to how attribute access for modules works and how it can modified, as pointed out by [PEP 562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/)). However the following snippet indicates that this is not the case:

```
import sys

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = sys.modules['__main__']

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return getattr(self.main, name)
        except AttributeError:
            return 'Fallback for "{}"'.format(name)

sys.modules['__main__'] = Wrapper()
print(undefined)
```

which raises `NameError: name 'undefined' is not defined`.

On the other hand we can add names by modifying `sys.modules['__main__'].__dict__` or using `setattr`:

```
import sys

# Either ...
sys.modules['__main__'].__dict__['undefined'] = 'not anymore'
# Or ...
setattr(sys.modules['__main__'], 'undefined', 'not anymore')

print(undefined)  # Works.
```

So I suspected that maybe it's the module's `__dict__` attribute (or equivalently `__builtins__.globals`) which is checked directly, sidestepping `getattr` on the module object. Extending the above example however shows that this is not the case:

```
import sys

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = sys.modules['__main__']

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return getattr(self.main, name)
        except AttributeError:
            return 'Fallback for "{}"'.format(name)

    @property
    def __dict__(self):
        class D:
            def __contains__(*args):
                return True

            def __getitem__(__, item):
                return getattr(self, item)

        return D()

sys.modules['__main__'] = Wrapper()
sys.modules['builtins'].globals = lambda: sys.modules['__main__'].__dict__
print(globals()['undefined'])  # Works.
print(undefined)               # Raises NameError.
```

## Questions

1. What is the exact definition of *scopes* and *namespaces*?
2. How are names exactly resolved (what steps are taken and which resources are checked in order to determine if a name exists)?
3. In what way does name resolution involve scopes and namespaces?
4. Why does the above example using `Wrapper` fail (while it does work on "general" module attribute access, as per [PEP 562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/))?

Answer (score -1):

Your's is a very interesting question, since I don't have a clear answer let's run some experiments.

First let's change your code a bit:

```
# file main.py
import sys
print(sys.modules['__main__'])
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = sys.modules['__main__']

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return getattr(self.main, name)
        except AttributeError:
            return 'Fallback for "{}"'.format(name)

sys.modules['__main__'] = Wrapper()
print(sys.modules['__main__'])
print(undefined)
```

It will print

```
<module '__main__' from 'main.py'>
<__main__.Wrapper object at 0x000001F87601BE48>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(undefined)
NameError: name 'undefined' is not defined
```

So we still have `__main__` as a module here, and `Wrapper` class is inside it.

Docs says:

> > A module’s `__name__` is set equal to `__main__` when read from standard input, a script, or from an interactive prompt.

So that means our `sys.modules['__main__'] = Wrapper()` line is meant to subsitute an already loaded module, with something from inside that module (!!).

OTOH, importing `main.py` from the REPL (the other case where a `__main__` module is created), totally messes with **everything** so some substitution is happening at that time.

Summarizing:

As far as I can see, it requires some deep dark magic to change `__main__` from inside a running module, maybe if we use `importlib.reload` and mess with the cached modules?

Doing that from other module seems ok, but (the example) messes with things, and name resolution breaks, i.e the Wapper class doesn't resolve previous names as you believe it should.

PD.

Sorry if this is not the *experienced* answer you wanted and seems more like a commentary. I did it as an experiment to test your hypothesis and maybe find some results.

Comment: *"[...] subsitute an already loaded module, with something from inside that module (!!)."* I don't see how this is problematic, it's the same what you would use in < Python 3.7 to modify module attribute access in general. *"importing main.py from the REPL, totally messes with everything [...]"* I'm not sure what you mean by that or how it is relevant, but importing the main script doesn't cause any problems. *"Doing that from other module seems ok, but it messes with things, and name resolution breaks."* What exactly do you mean here? Anyway the whole thing is rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: Editing for clarification

Comment: Again, your comments are (still) not clear. Specifically (again): 1. *"subsitute an already loaded module, with something from inside that module "* That is exactly what you use to modify module attribute access; so what do you mean by mentioning it here? 2. *"importing `main.py` from the REPL (the other case where a `__main__` module is created), totally messes with everything"* Actually that's wrong. Importing `main.py` will create a module called `'main'`; and it doesn't "mess" with anything. 3. *"to test your hypothesis"* There's no hypothesis in the OP, so what were you actually testing?

Comment: Actually that's not wrong, maybe poorly written, running the REPL creates a `__main__` module, importing `main.py` overwrites the `__main__` module (because of your example) and while I was expecting name resolution to keep working, it didn't. That lead me to believe that substituting `__main__` with a wrapper (the way you did)  while possible might be troublesome because of the way module loading works. Your hypotheses that *name resolution* does not work as explained fails to prove itself

Comment: To clarify, running the interpreter indeed creates a `__main__` module, however importing a file called `main.py` will create a module named `"main"` (not `"__main__"`). Furthermore, importing a module will *not* overwrite another module with the same name that is already loaded (for that you would need to use `importlib.reload`). So even if you called your file `__main__.py` (instead of `main.py`) and did `import __main__` in the interpreter, just nothing would happen, as a module called `__main__` is already loaded. Hence what you claim is wrong and I don't see how it answers my question.

Comment: How do we move this into a chat?

Comment: You can't before prompted by the system. Anyway I see no reason for debate here. If you want to learn more about the Python import system I suggest you [this article](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html). As your answer stands, I find it unclear and its relevance with respect to the OP is not apparent. In addition some of the things you mention (also in comments) are wrong (as pointed out above). You are welcome to update your answer once you gained more insight into the topic but as it stands it is not appropriate.